# Is ETH 2.0 going to have many L2 layers running with it?

Tags: eth-2.0, layer-2

Is it true that ETH 2.0 will just have many L2 layers running with it, such as Polygon, so

1. ETH 2.0 needs these L2 layers
2. These L2 layers are not going to go away just because of ETH 2.0 rolling out

?

Answer (score 0):

The merge will not change anything to the protocols and L2 already existing. You have an [excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N10a1EBhBc) by Danny Ryan that explains why the Merge and Eth 2.0.
Your question is probably also referring to the *shards* which could be used for L2 solutions. For now the only specifications about shards can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/tree/dev/specs/sharding) and I need to study this in more details to understand how they will use this for L2 solutions.